# How to (de)serialize a strongly typed JSON dictionary in Serde?

Tags: json, rust, serde

I am writing a Rust application that handles JSON messages from a TypeScript client with a public interface. I have written some code using `serde_derive` and it works well, but I can't figure out how to implement dictionaries; e.g.:

```
{
  "foo" : { "data" : 42 },
  "bar" : { "data" : 1337 }
}
```

Here the keys are the strings `"foo"` and `"bar"` and the dictionary's values follow this schema:

```
use serde_derive;
use serde_json::Number;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct DictionaryValue {
    data: Number,
}
```

I am looking to access the JSON data in this manner:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Dictionary {
    key: String,
    value: DictionaryValue,
}
```

How can I (de)serialize my JSON data into/from `Dictionary` using Serde?

Comment: You must use a [hashmap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html)

Comment: @Stargateur No, any associative container like [`BTreeMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html) can be used. You can even implement one on your own. See the docs [here](https://serde.rs/impl-serialize.html#serializing-a-sequence-or-map) and [here](https://serde.rs/impl-deserialize.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a logic error in your code. The structure in your JSON file describes an associative array but your `Dictionary` does not support multiple key-value-pairs. As [Stargateur stated in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49717966/how-to-deserialize-a-strongly-typed-json-dictionary-in-serde#comment86448934_49717966), you may use [`HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html) as  `Serde` has `Serialize` and `Deserialize` implementations for [`HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html).

Instead of using a single key-value-pair, you can rewrite your `Dictionary` as

```
type Dictionary = HashMap<String, DictionaryValue>;
```

and you can retrieve the data for example by

```
let dict: Dictionary = serde_json::from_str(json_string).unwrap();
```

If you now want to wrap everything in a `Dictionary`-struct it will look like this:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Dictionary {
    inner: HashMap<String, DictionaryValue>,
}
```

The problem is, that `serde_json` now expects

```
{
  "inner": {
    "foo" : { "data" : 42 },
    "bar" : { "data" : 1337 }
  }
}
```

To get rid of this, you can add the `serde(flatten)` [attribute](https://serde.rs/attributes.html) to `Dictionary`:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Dictionary {
    #[serde(flatten)]
    inner: HashMap<String, DictionaryValue>,
}
```

If [`HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html) or any [`BTreeMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html) from `std` does not fit your needs, you can also implement your `Dictionary` on your own. See the docs [here](https://serde.rs/impl-serialize.html#serializing-a-sequence-or-map) and [here](https://serde.rs/impl-deserialize.html) for more details.